# OrderBy using withCount on Polymorphic relationship not working on Laravel 5.2 / 5.3

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, sql-order-by

I love the *withCount* method on Eloquent to orderBy a relationship count. Let's say we'd want to get some *posts* ordered by the number of favorites they have, in a "normal" one-to-many relationship:

```
$posts = $query->withCount('favorites')->orderBy('favorites_count', 'DESC')->get();
```

That works perfectly, as I said, in *normal* relationship. BUT when is used with a polymorphic relationship, it seems to take a huge amount of time so for more than 100 - 1000 elements it fails, in both Laravel 5.2 and 5.3.

Is there anything I'm missing? I've used polymorphic relationships quite often, I don't think that there is a problem with the relationship itself but just with the withCount method.

Note: I can't use sortBy, it must be orderBy. And I know I could do it with Fluent query builder, but I'm interested on using Eloquent this way.

Thanks!